# Mouseover/out apenas em um elemento do menu dentro de vários pego pelo seletor jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quando passo o mouse em um item do menu todos recebem o efeito do mouseover/out.
Gostaria de saber se qual procedimento/função usar para quando passar o mouse no menu aplicar o efeito apenas nesse item do menu.

```
<div id="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-item"></div>

    <div class="grid-item"></div>

    <div class="grid-item"></div>

    <div class="grid-item"></div>

</div>

<script>

    var grid_item = $('.grid-item').ea;

    $(document).ready(() => {

        // Adicionando o evento com mouseover.
        grid_item.mouseover( () => {
            grid_item.addClass('item-hover');
        });

        // Removendo o evento com mouseout.
        grid_item.mouseout( () => {
            grid_item.removeClass('item-hover');
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jQuery tem um método próprio para chamar dois eventos ao mesmo tempo, o [.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$(elemento).hover(
   function(){
      // função do mouseenter (quando passa o mouse)
   },
   function(){
      // função do mouseleave (quando retira o mouse)
   }
);
```

Exemplo adicionando a classe:

```js
$(".grid-item").hover(
   function(){
      $(this).addClass("item-hover");
   },
   function(){
      $(this).removeClass("item-hover");
   }
);
```

```css
.item-hover{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>

    <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>

    <div class="grid-item">item 3</div>

    <div class="grid-item">item 4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo! Seu código me ajudou a encontrar o problema do porquê estava selecionando tudo. Acredito que eu estava guardando em uma variável a classe grid-item, e com isso não funcionava. A partir do momento que passei a pegar o elemento direto do código $('.grid-item') e usar o $(this) passou a selecionar apenas um.
Não entendi muito bem o porquê, se souber me informar, estaria agradecido.
Além de saber o momento exato de armazenar em variáveis item/ns pelo do seletor ou usar direto.

Comment: O `$(this)` representa o elemento que chamou o evento.